# Admin Logout Error in django-nonrel

Tags: django-admin, django-nonrel, djangoappengine

HI,

I am facing logout problem while using admin app in django-nonrel

It is a great project.. anyone knows why i am facing [DoesNotExist at /admin/logout/](http://dpaste.com/331889/) error

It would be great if i could get some inputs and make it work.

Answer (score 4):

I'm new to Django and have run into this same problem.  The cause is that the "sites" table, which should contain an entry whose id is equal to the SITE_ID value in settings.py, is empty.  I imagine this is supposed to get set automatically, but I haven't figured out why it isn't in this case.  You can add the entry manually by going into the shell (after making sure runserver isn't running) and entering:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
import settings

Site(id=settings.SITE_ID, domain="localhost", name="django-testapp").save()
```

Comment: Hi Zach , thank you for the input..I too saw in the admin (default app to manage db ) that Sites table is empty as you have highlighted. I can add an entry as you have suggested, however there is a small query. I upload the django-testapp on GAE , Will I Have to add any other entry as domain there is not "localhost" ?

Comment: You won't be able to add an additional entity, because you can't have two entities with the same SITE_ID value as the key.  Your production table will need to be different than your development table.

Comment: Hey zach .. thanks for your inputs .. what do you suggest , should i change my SITE_ID(locally in settings.py), deploy on GAE  and add the SIDE_ID as you have suggested by logging in remote shell of my app deployed on GAE? What should be my domain and name of app, can i keep it as domain : "appid.appspot.com" and name as "appid" ?  One problem i see as maintaining 02 settings.py. Please suggest !!

Comment: or i should keep 02 copies of my project (local) for development and one for deploying on production. Please suggest how you do it ?

Comment: The best solution is probably to find out why it's necessary to manually create the entity in the first place.  Keeping two copies of the app is certainly not a good solution.